# Windows 8.1 Metro Apps Not Working (Including Built-In Ones Like "Computer Settings")

Tags: windows-8.1, services, modern-ui

I don't care about 3rd party metro applications, but i can't enter "Computer Settings" either..

When i enter control panel/User Accounts/ and click to "add a new user" some metro ui tries to open and it gives an error. (It doesn't give any technical information about error)

After my investigation, i found out that in services.msc "AppX Deployment Service(AppXSVC)" is not running. It's startup type is set to Automatic but it's not running. When i try to start it, it gives this error : "Error 1058: The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it." But it's not disabled..

I tried Sfc /scannow command in CMD it didn't find any error.

Edit: I know there are lots of questions like this but my problem is slightly differs from them.

Comment: Could you try updating the windows 8.1 and rebooting the machine..

Comment: Windows Update says that my computer is "up to date". It doesn't find any new updates.

Comment: Hi there. Does running the [Apps Troubleshooter](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=268423) fix your issue at all? Even if Windows Update says that your computer is "up to date," does clicking the `check for updates` option off to the left bring up any indication that some updates are available?

Comment: Apps Troubleshooter says that some services are corrupt. When i click check for updates it doesn't find new updates.

Comment: Windows firewall should be on or set to automatic. Make sure that it is not turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Found this as a life saver - you repair the shop, afterwards reinstall all apps
http://blogs.technet.com/b/ouc1too/archive/2013/10/19/windows-app-store-doesn-t-load-after-8-1-upgrade.aspx

In the Administrator Command Prompt

type or paste the following command:

powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register $Env:SystemRoot\WinStore\AppxManifest.xml

hit Enter.

Now in that same Administrator Command Prompt type or paste: start "" "ms-windows-store:"

afterwards - reinstall all not working apps